# Text doesn't show

Tags: html, css

```css
.sport
{
  content: url("../img/sport.png");
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
  top: 61px;
  height: 310px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sportsandactivis
{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
  top: 142px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 48px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat',Helvetica,Arial,serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 22.0px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 27.0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sport">
  <p class="sportsandactivis">Sports and Activis</p>
</div>
```

the image is displayed correctly but the text inside "sports and activitis" not appear, why?

Comment: Because you are completely replacing the content of `.sport` by using `content: url("../img/sport.png")` …

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/150x150);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
```

And remove content from `.sports` class

```css
.sport {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/150x150);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  top: 61px;
  height: 310px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sportsandactivis {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  top: 142px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 48px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, Arial, serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 22.0px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 27.0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sport">
  <p class="sportsandactivis">Sports and Activis</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your text doesn't appear because you are using `content`! That completely replaces the content of your `.sport` element !…

`content` is generally used to generate content on `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, but it shouldn't be used to alter the content of HTML elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

… You must want to use `background-image` instead:

```css
.sport
{ /* Changed "content" to "background-image", and added a working meow image */ 
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/300/310"); 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
  top: 61px;
  height: 310px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sportsandactivis
{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
  top: 142px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 48px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat',Helvetica,Arial,serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 22.0px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 27.0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sport">
  <p class="sportsandactivis">Sports and Activis</p>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change css inside .sport from content to background-image

```css
.sport
{
  background-image: url("../img/sport.png");
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
  top: 61px;
  height: 310px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sportsandactivis
{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
  top: 142px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 48px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat',Helvetica,Arial,serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 22.0px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 27.0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sport">
  <p class="sportsandactivis">Sports and Activis</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.sport` class as a `background-image` currently the way you've coded it, the `.sport` class will cover the `.sportandactivis` class.

Try:

```
 width: 100%;
    background-image: url("../img/sport.png");
    background-position: 0%, 0%, 50%, 50%;
    background-size: auto, cover;
```

Then position the `.sport` class over the top with either `absolute` positioning or `flex` positioning Like so:

```
.sport {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sport {
    position:absolute; 
    top:50%; 
    left:50%; 
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your CSS or HTML, we can fix this in two method.

**Method 1:**

Change your `content` to `background-image` in CSS.

Please check the code here https://jsfiddle.net/59ozuesp/

**Method 2:**

Change your HTML like this:

```
<div class="sport"></div>
<p class="sportsandactivis">Sports and Activis</p>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5gwbax4d/

Actually the `content` property is used for `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, to insert generated content. When you used `content` property that will be completely replace your content. I hope you understand.